# TCPDF +DOMPDF: PROBLEMA PARA FIRMAR PDF

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, tcpdf

Estoy utilizando dompdf para generar el documento pdf a travez de la vista blade.php (buena opcion ya que me carga estilos css). Sin embargo no genera firma digital, para esto estoy usando tcpdf sin embargo nose como unir estas dos librerías para lograr firmar el documento generado

```
public function imprimir(){
    $html_contect = '<h1> PDF GENERADO USANDO TCPDF EN LARAVEL </h1>';
    $info = array(
        'Name' => 'TCPDF',
        'Location' => 'Office',
        'Reason' => 'Testing TCPDF',
        'ContactInfo' => 'http://www.tcpdf.org',
        );


    $imagenBase64 = base64_encode($contenidoImagen);
    $pdf = \OPDF::loadView('index2', compact('imagenBase64'));    
    $certificate = 'file://'.realpath('tcpdf.crt');
    
    PDF::AddPage();
    PDF::setSignature($certificate, $certificate, 'tcpdfdemo', '',2,$info );
    
    PDF::setSignatureAppearance(60,10,15,15);
    PDF::addEmptySignatureAppearance(10,10,60,60);
    PDF::writeHtml($html_contect, true,false,true,false, '');

    return $pdf -> stream('reporte.pdf');

    
}
```

Comment: No puedes combinar ambas librerías, pero hay otra para [firmar PDF's existentes](https://github.com/lsnepomuceno/laravel-a1-pdf-sign), revisa a ver si te sirve.

Comment: listo gracias por la info estaré informando si funcionó